# JavaScript Math Percentage

Tags: javascript, html, math, percentage

I have an element where I need to remove a percentage of it.

I've stored the original price as a variable and have another variable to work out the price after the percentage has been taken.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="price">420.29</div>
```

I want to remove 8% off `.price` and have it fixed to two decimal places and store it as a variable.

Here's the JS I have so far:

```
var price = $(".price").html();
var priceafter = Math.round(price - price * 8 / 100).toFixed(2);
```

`priceafter` returns back as 387.00 instead of 386.66.

## Update

Thanks to @datasage for point out I was using `Math.round`. This is what I've changed it to and it seems to be working:

```
var price = $(".price").html();
var priceafter = (price - price * 8 / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Math.round` will round your result to the nearest whole number. You can used just `toFixed` Which will round it correctly to 386.67

Comment: Aha, that's why! Thanks, I'll update the question with what I done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var price = parseFloat($(".price").html());
```

Comment: Or even better, `parseFloat($(".price").text())`.

Comment: Nothing changes. What does `parseFloat` do? Is it the `toFixed`?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin That actually changes `price` to 420.2942 and `priceafter` doesn't change at all.